# Is it possible to upload folders?

Tags: file, file-upload, directory

This is my scenario
[image: 1]

So, using

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

is it possible to upload these 4 elements(the 2 files and the folders(with their own content))?

if i do this the only elements that are going to be "selected" are the .txt files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

Yes it possible to upload folder kindly check by below code

```
<input type="file" webkitdirectory mozdirectory />
```

Multiple files upload but it must be in same folder:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
```

Also go through that [one](https://jsfiddle.net/kevalpadia/vk6Ldzae/)

Hope it helps!! thanks